# Deleting custom objects from a listview within a fragment using onClick XML

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm still learning a lot about programming.
I've currently set up my own listview item layout to display a custom object.
Within this custom listview layout, there's an image button that has an onClick method associated to it.

I've realised that the onClick is passed back to the parent activity, but i'm not sure how to remove my listview item as my arraylist of the custom object is within the fragment.

I'm probably not explaining myself very well, so here is code snippets to go with it.

---

Image button XML within custom listview layout:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/deleteitem"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@null"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/deleteItemButton"
        android:onClick="delItem"/>
```

OnClick method in parent Activity:

```
public void delItem(View v) {
    _ItemObject itemToRemove = (_ItemObject) v.getTag();

    ItemList_Fragment itemlistclass = new ItemList_Fragment();
    itemlistclass.removeItem(itemToRemove);

}
```

removeItem method found in fragment:

```
public void removeItem(_ItemObject itemToRemove) {

    adapter.remove(itemToRemove);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

This error received says that "adapter" in my fragment is null. This is earlier initialised when the fragment is created. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make it so complex. Remove `android:onClick="delItem"` from the view and attach listener in your `getView()` . 
Initialize `deleteItemButton` and `setOnClickListener()` -

```
deleteItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    _ItemObject itemToRemove = (_ItemObject) v.getTag();
                    remove(itemToRemove);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Sorry for my potential stupidity here, but i'm getting the "nullPointerException" as the deleteItemButton Image Button is in a different layout technically. I just call it within my adapter. So when i initialise deleteItemButton in my fragment, it returns null as "technically" it doesn't exist in that view. I can paste more code if it helps?

Comment: I think i might have just figured out what you meant. Give me 5 minutes :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!